# Getting the last 13 digits of a large number

Tags: javascript, math

I am writing a function that is supposed to do powers, but only display the last n digits specified. It is working great... mostly. For some reason when I specify how many of the last digits I want, it works fine all the way up to and including the number 12. Any digit amount above 12 seems to give me a very strange number. I know I must be missing something obvious, but I really don't see it.

Here is the code:

```
function power(base, exponent, digits) {
total = base;
for(i = 1; i < exponent; i++) {
    total =  total * base;

    if(total.toString().length > digits)  {
        total = total.toString().substr(total.toString().length - digits, digits);
        }
    }

return total;
}
```

So, for some examples (displaying 12 digits and lower works fine):

If I do power(999, 999, 1) I end up with => 9

If I do power(999, 999, 5) I end up with => 98999

If I do power(999, 999, 12) I end up with => 000499998999

Here is where it starts messing up:

If I do power(999, 999, 13) I end up with  => 5710054009000

If I do power(999, 999, 14) I end up with  => '79077027006000'

At first I thought I was hitting some kind of integer limit and scientific notation was screwing things up, but I don't think that is the case, because it should work up to 20 digits.

I suspect it is something wrong with the way I am reducing the string in the if statement. But I am not sure why it wouldn't mess up for calculations below 13 digits.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how IEEE 794 floating point works?

Comment: I have some idea. But I didn't think it would lose precision at 13 digits. The idea behind my function there is to never let it work with numbers that high. It never multiplies anything above the 13th digit.

Comment: @renosis A 13 digit number multiplied by a 3 digit number is (up to) a 16 digit number. Double-precision floats are only exact for up to 15 digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a function to compute b^e (mod m). A good algorithm is known as [*square and multiply*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation):

```
Algorithm PowerMod: Compute b^e (mod m) with b, e and m all positive integers.
1. [Initialize] Set r := 1.
2. [Terminate when finished] If e == 0, return r and stop.
3. [Multiply if odd] If e is odd, set r := r * b (mod n).
4. [Square and iterate] Set e := floor(e / 2). Set b := b * b (mod n). Go to Step 2.
```

Then to make your computation, say PowerMod(999, 999, 10^14); you should get 17000499998999.

Comment: I tried this, I must be missing something here. This does not give values above 20 digits. I am just going to have to convert every computation to a string that build on to for every place I calculate, aren't I?

Comment: The PowerMod algorithm is correct. You need a big-integer library that doesn't restrict the range of integers you are able to compute. I don't know javascript, so I can't tell you if big integers are built in or if there are libraries available that provide big integers.